# How to prevent buildup of memory usage on GPU PyTorch 0.3

Tags: pytorch

Using this code I get an out of memory error after a few iterations. I've isolated the problem to appending to the self.ground_truth variables, I think for some reason it stays stored on the GPU. x and gt_class_ids start out on the GPU. I'm trying to load it into the CPU so that the self.ground_truth variables don't take up memory on the GPU. I'm kind of new to PyTorch and Python and also I'm restricted to version 0.3

```
x = x.cpu()[0]
gt_class_ids = gt_class_ids.cpu()[0]

for feature in x:
    self.ground_truth.append(feature)
for id in gt_class_ids:
    self.ground_truth_ids.append(id)

torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with 0.3 version, but I think you can put a breakpoint at `x = x.cpu()[0]` to check where `x` locates after that operation. The locations where your `self.ground_truth` and `self.ground_truch_ids` are defined also need to be found out.

Comment: self.ground_truth and self.ground_truth_ids are simply lists I created using self.ground_truth = [] They aren't on the GPU right?